# Access - Create a button that fills in textboxes on multiple forms/subforms

Tags: ms-access, vba

I can make a button that fills in required fields to max values for what I need on my forms. But I have them all on separate forms. Is there a way to create a button/checkbox on just my main form that inputs all that info on all the forms/subforms? Rather than have 7 of similar buttons on all 7 forms. Trying to save time and human error when creating new clients...

Currently using Access 2003 but in the midst's of migrating to 2016 (huge jump I know...)

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to create a control (command button or check box) that will set default values for all of the required fields on a form and its 6 subforms, not 7 separate main forms. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, hoping it's simple lol

Comment: Will the default value be the same for all fields or will it be unique to the field?

Comment: They will be unique, theres tons of textboxes, checkboxes, I think even some radio buttons... but they're all differen't. 
ie: 
DailyMax.Value = "99999"
RoomType.Value = "Private"
CoInsurance.Value = True

Comment: Why have you chosen to set the fields to required if you aren't really requiring the user to fill them out? Because they will be unique, you will have to programmatically set the value of each one in the VBA for your command button's OnClick event. This is doable, but I'm not sure it's a good idea, because if you set values to something that is functionally meaningless (like 9999) then it's not better than having a null value, and can make some things such as averages less meaningful.

Comment: It's a benefits company, when creating new clients we have a benefits class that has max coverage (100%) of everything they submit. When creating/adding clients to them, we input what they are covered for. there's a few different coverage options under each heading: Medical, Dental, Vision, etc. and these all have separate values for maximum/total coverage. 
For this, I figured being able to just click a checkbox/button to enter all those values in at once instead of entering info wrong, missing values, etc. that the human error aspect would be taken out as save about 10+ min of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this the same way you did on the main form, but you will need to know the syntax for referencing controls on subforms.
Go to the command button and edit the code for the Click event.

```
     Private Sub CommandButtonName_Click()
          Me.MainField.Value = "default" 'Set fields on the main form to their default values like this
          Me!SubformName.Form!SubformField.Value = "default" 'Set fields on the subforms with this syntax
    End Sub
```

You will have to do this for every field in each subform. It also might be wise to program an "undo" button... I'll leave that up to you!

This is not the most elegant solution, but I think for your purposes the time saved for the users will be worth the time setting the defaults within the command button's event.

Comment: I can work with that! I can make a clear/undo from that as well. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't like me lol. Me!dentalheader.Form!personmax.Value = "99999" gives me an error "can't find the field 'dentalheader' referred to in your expression"...

Comment: Make sure you are referencing the subform control on the main form. If you use the subform creation wizard the name of the subform control and the subform itself may not match depending on what type of object your subform is built on (anything but a form will result in Access naming your subform control something like "Tablename subform" but if you update the name of the subform in the navigation bar, the control retains the old name). You can fix this by clicking on the outline of the subform in the design view of the main form, then going to the "Other" tab and renaming the subform control.

Comment: Awesome, got the subform working. But how do I get it to fill the fields on other main forms? Each of the headings are on different forms, ie: Dental (has a sub), Medical (has it's main then 6 buttons which open 6 forms, no subs), etc

Comment: it's basically the same, but you replace `Me!` with `[Forms]![MainFormName]` to get something like `[Forms]![MainFormName].MainField.Value = "default"` or  `[Forms]![MainFormName].SubformName.Form!SubformField.Value = "default"`

Comment: This was working until I noticed that if one of the forms is not open, it can't find it. Is there a way to reference a form that isn't open?
EDIT: I found that you can't reference a closed form. Without slowing this down immensely, can I pull a form and just make it visible = false?

Comment: You *could* do that, but I think it would be better to open all of the forms you will be auto-filling at the beginning of your command button's subroutine, and close them at the end of the subroutine. Use `DoCmd.OpenForm` and `DoCmd.Close` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to open forms via code and perform actions onto the textboxes etc.
But as Elizabeth Ham said, you would need to specify each action.
This can make your main form extremely slow.

```
Sub EnterDataOnForm()
Dim clsFrm As Form
Set clsFrm = Forms("frmNr1")

clsFrm.txtNr1.Value = "Test 1"
clsFrm.txtNr2.Value = "Test 2"

Set clsFrm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Even if it adds 10-20 seconds of wait time, I would think/hope that the user would not be frustrated as is it saves the input time and double checking..

Comment: Well users can be unpredictable :)   I put a msgbox in the end of my code so the user can see when everything is saved/changed (if it involves important data). Some might be against this, but I find it helpful as I can say to users that once the pop-up appears everything is ok.